# React Native textAlign:'justify' not working in RTL

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I used following `style` for `justify` my text, but it is working fine in `ltr` but not working in `rtl`

```
style={{
marginTop:20,
fontSize: 16, 
textAlign:'justify'
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`writingDirection:'rtl'` property with `textAlign:'justify'`

```
style={{
marginTop:20,
fontSize: 16, 
textAlign:'justify',
writingDirection:'rtl'
}}
```